# "play a joke on" or "play jokes on"?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Is the following sentence correct?

> Sometimes he likes to play a joke on his sister.

I feel like it should be

> Sometimes he likes to play jokes on his sister.

but I'm not sure about it. Could anyone help to explain it please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though both are fine, the second one does sound more correct to me. I think the first would be implying that sometimes he likes to play **one** joke on his sister. The second sounds better because he could be playing just one or more than one joke and he also does this frequently hence jokes plural.

Comment: Agreed, the only time I could think of to use the first one would be if it was a specific joke you frequently liked playing on them, rather than jokes in general.